# Downloading File in ASP mvc .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, download

I Put The Download Link in jqgrid, my Files are Stored on server not in database, files are of different types(extension)
i want user should download file when he clicks on download link

Code  For Loading jqgrid is as Follws

```
public object GetJSONFormatProjectDetails(List<ProjectMasterDTO> listProjectDTO, int SkipCount)
    {
        var data = (listProjectDTO.Select(c => new
        {
            id = c.ProjectID,
            cell = new[]
                        {
                            c.ProjectName,
                            c.OfficeName,
                            c.ProjectType,
                            c.ProjectNature,
                            c.EntrepreneurName,
                            c.Year + " Years " +c.Month  + " Months " + c.Day + " Days" ,
                            c.ConcessionWEFdate,
                            c.ProjectStartDate,
                            c.ProjectEndDate,
                            c.isRoadApplicable,
                            (c.FilePath != "NA" ) ? "<a href='#' style='color:green' onclick='DownLoadFile(\""+URLEncrypt.EncryptParameters(new string[]{ "filepath =" +c.FilePath.Replace("/","$").Replace(" ","#").Trim()})+"\");return false;'>"+(c.FilePath != "NA" ? "DownLoad":"Not Available") + " </a>" : "<span style='color:Red' >Not Available</span>"

                        }
        })).ToArray().Skip(SkipCount);
        return data;
    }
```

JS File Code is As Follows

```
function DownLoadFile(param) {
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/GetFile?parameter=" + param,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    async: false
});
```

}

Code in Controller as follows

```
  public ActionResult GetFile(string parameter)
    {
        string queryStringParameters = Request.QueryString["parameter"];

        if (queryStringParameters == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Url is tampered");
        }

        string[] parameterArray = queryStringParameters.Split('/');

        string param = null;
        string hash = null;
        string key = null;
        if (parameterArray.Length == 3)
        {
            param = parameterArray[0];
            hash = parameterArray[1];
            key = parameterArray[2];
        }
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = URLEncrypt.DecryptParameters(new string[] { param, hash, key });
            string FilePath =string.Empty ;
            parameters.TryGetValue("filepath", out FilePath);
            FilePath = FilePath.Replace('$','\\');

            // DownloadFile(FilePath);

            string name = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(FilePath);
            string type = "";
            // set known types based on file extension  
            if (ext != null)
            {
                switch (ext.ToLower())
                {

                    case ".pdf":
                        type = "Application/pdf";
                        break;

                    case ".doc":

                    case ".docx":
                        type = "Application/msword";
                        break;

                    case ".jpg":

                    case ".bmp":

                    case ".tiff":

                    case ".png":

                    case ".gif":

                    case ".jpeg":
                        type = "Application/Image";
                        break;
                    default:
                        type = "Application";
                        break;

                }
            }
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);

            if (type != "")
            {
                Response.ContentType = type;
            }
            String FullFilePath = @"F:\MHTOLL\ContractUploadDetails\" + name;
            //return File(new FileStream(path + fileName, FileMode.Open), "text/plain", fileName);
          //  return File(new FileStream(FullFilePath, FileMode.Open), type, name);
            return File(FullFilePath, type,name);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Dont mind now about return null and exception handling

also suggest for displaying .gif animation for downloading file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use an AJAX call to download a file.

I think this answer will get you what you want. Be sure to read the comments about the download prompt and MIME types. [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue and realized that AJAX will not work to download a file. Try an ActionLink instead:

`@Html.ActionLink("ButtonName", "controllerFunctionName", "controllerName", new { functionParamName = paramValue })`

And you would include your function in the controller:

`public ActionResult controllerFunctionName(type functionParamName){
    // do your download here
}`

Comment: Simply put, AJAX doesn't work well with the Response.function calls. I don't have a reason why however, would appreciate if someone could explain this for me.

Comment: Here's where I originally posted my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458477/response-writefile-not-working-asp-net-mvc-4-5/15577763#15577763. I was using AJAX but did not see that as the issue. I thought the bug was in the controller function.