# Response.WriteFile() -- not working asp net mvc 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, savefiledialog, response.write

I've looked at many resources and the following should work, however my save as dialog box is never showing (not browser specific):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
string downloadName = "Request "+request.RequestID+ "_researchExport.doc";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", 
    new System.IO.FileInfo(FileName).Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    string.Format("attachment; filename={0};", downloadName));
Response.WriteFile(FileName);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

The file definitely exists. I've also tried the following:

1. Using `Response.TransmitFile(FileName)` instead
2. Leaving out `Response.End()`
3. Leaving out the `Content-Length` header
4. Using `this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response`

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated

Comment: I have attempted to use the suggested answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897458/asp-net-download-file-to-client-browser but this also did not work

Comment: Update: I did get an HTTP connection closed error on Response.End(), but cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. I was using Ajax to call this function from one of my views. This didn't work (I am not sure why), but I think it may be because I have multiple controllers. Calling this from `@HTML.ActionLink()` had the prompt display properly.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's your only problem, but the file name in the `Content-Disposition` header [is supposed to be a `quoted-string`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1), so you'll need to add quotes around it, particularly since it contains spaces;

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", downloadName));
```

On a side note, `Response.End()` also flushes the buffer, so your `Response.Flush()` is redundant.

Comment: Here's the file name: C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Project\MyTest\MyTest\researcherExport.doc which contains no spaces.

Comment: @lohiaguitar91 `string downloadName = "Request "+request.RequestID+ "_researchExport.doc";` would seem to build a file name `Request xx_researchExport.doc` with a space in it.

Comment: ah yes. I did remove the space to now read `"Request+request.RequestID+ "_researchExport.doc"` however still no download prompt. Checked many different resources and it seems like what I'm doing should work. Surrounding it in a try-catch block did not produce any exception.