# Whenever i click on view online button my file doesn't show proper pdf in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

when I click on it my file doesn't open properly [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72nkv.png)

```
string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
            Response.ContentType = ContentType;

          //  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename"+Path.GetFileName(filePath)+".pdf");

            Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: try this:
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"

Comment: There is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458477/response-writefile-not-working-asp-net-mvc-4-5

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to get your work done,

```
string pdfPath = Server.MapPath("~/SomePDFFile.pdf");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(pdfPath);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Comment: it says file not found