# [Content_Types].xml unknown error in ASP.NET Core 5 (EPPlus)

Tags: epplus, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to use EPPlus to manipulate my xlsm template and download to client. I believe there is no issue with excel package as I am able to save the package locally. But I need content disposition to download to client when it is live...

I have tried many different ways, return file, return filecontentresult, return streamcontentresult but all result in the same unknown error (attached in screenshot, as I could not translate it)..

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Solved... you cannot use Ajax to call excel export function in controller. instead, call directly using html action link and return file ActionResult and it will initiate download in client browser.

similar resolution can be found here.
[Response.WriteFile() -- not working asp net mvc 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458477/response-writefile-not-working-asp-net-mvc-4-5)